# How to query JSON in MySql

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate

My database has email as ID and another column zipCode as JSON type. Querying directly in MySQL like this is working:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE 
    JSON_CONTAINS(testJson, '12345');
```

So `testJson` is the JSON type column with JSON arrays like:

```
[22079, 22310, 12345, 65412, 78954]
```

I'm trying to replicate the above in Hibernate:

```
session.createQuery( "from " + ZipCodes.class.getSimpleName() + " where JSON_CONTAINS(zipCodes, zipCodes=:zipCode )")
                .setParameter("zipCode", zipCode)
                .getResultList();
```

But I'm getting this exception:

```
unexpected AST node: ( near line 1, column 60 [ where JSON_CONTAINS(zipCodes, zipCodes=:zipCode )]
```

I don't know how to construct my `JSON_CONTAINS` clause.

Comment: Try it with `JSON_CONTAINS(zipCodes, :zipCode )`. I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: I've tried that. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error trying to do the same thing. This solution should work easily with your example, because my JSON was more complicated.

Constructing the `JSON_CONTAINS` in hibernate is slightly different than MySql. So assuming that your **zipCodes** JSON is the same as the `testJson`, here is the HQL syntax that worked for me:

`JSON_CONTAINS(zipCodes, '12345') = 1`

Basically you need to add the  `= 1`, which means the JSON_CONTAINS must evaluate to `true`.

**Note** that sometimes you might get an error because of `:zipCode` (mostly when dealing with collins in complicated JSON). In that case you can replace your value directly in the HQL. Something like this:

```
session.createQuery( "from " + ZipCodes.class.getSimpleName() + " where JSON_CONTAINS(zipCodes, '"+zipCode+"' )")
                .getResultList();
```

If your JSON is more complicated, then add a third parameter as the path.
More on that here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains